# Editing UITableViewCell by tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tags

I have been trying to find a simple answer to something I think something that shouldn't be that difficult but I just either can't find a decent answer or can't wrap my head around it.

I am trying to change/edit the text label content of one specific tableview cell. So for examples sake I would like a `UIButton` outside of the UITableView but in the same View Controller to change the text within row 2, while keeping the others the same.

I am aware you use `viewWithTag` but other than that I cannot figure this out! Please help....

This is my code so far

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    EntryCell *cell = (EntryCell *)[contentTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    cell.mainLabel.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.mainLabel.text = @"hello";

    return cell;

}

-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button {
    cell.mainLabel = (UILabel *)[contentTable viewWithTag:2];
    cell.mainLabel.text = @"goodbye";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use `viewWithTag`, use the below to get a reference to the cell

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button 
{
    EntryCell *cell = (EntryCell *)[tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0]];
    if(cell != nil)
    {
        cell.mainLabel.text = @"goodbye";
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

As david pointed out this will be overwritten if the cell is not visible as `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will be called again when it becomes visible. Overwriting this change with whatever you have specified.

You will need to update your data model after this so the change is permanent

Comment: Note that this will only work if the cell requested from cellForRowAtIndexPath is currently visible.

Comment: the issue isn't only that it will be overwritten.  cellForRowAtIndexPath: returns nil for cells that aren't currently visible.

Comment: @David ah yes, well then the edit stands, the data model should be updated for non visible rows as it will be "updated" in `cellFOrRowAtIndexPath`, ill add a nil check

Comment: Thanks so much! It was so simple. It worked with the default textLabel but I am struggling to get it to work with my custom cell text.

Comment: True enough, although at that point, my approach is to update the model and then invalidate the cell with reloadRows.  I hate having the same code multiple places :)

Comment: @David calling reloadRows will redraw all the rows on the screen, to update a row that isn't visible, all to avoid having one / a few lines of code duplicated? That sounds like over kill, and a waste of processing on a device with limited power supply

Comment: If you use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` specifying the single row you're updating, then only one row will be updated, and only if it's visible.  Yes, it's using a little bit more power, but that's negligible and you wind up with more maintainable code since you're only determining what the cell looks like and says in one place.  Alternately, if you're using the `configureCell:` approach then it's kind of moot, just reconfigure the cell if it's visible.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help everybody! Love this community.